# setEnabled(),setClickable() not working

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have used FrameLayout in which I have used two LinearLayouts. The second one is initially invisible but when I press a button on layout one, the second layout becomes visible and overlaps the first layout. What I want is when my second layout appears the first layout's elements should not be clickable (or enabled).
For this I have tried setEnabled(false) and setClickable(false) but both of these are not working I am not getting what is the problem.

Code is as follows

```
TableLayout table; 

EditText edit;  
ScrollView scroll;

Button btn_save;
Button btn_layer_save;
Button btn_cross;

AlertDialog alert_dialog;

LinearLayout layout_above;

int primary_selected;

RadioButton radio_geo;
RadioButton radio_alumni;

String geo = "no" ;
String alumni = "no" ;

int color;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_select_friends_edit_search);
    search_geo_name_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    search_id_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.register_scroll_view);

    btn_cross = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_cross);
    btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_save);
    btn_layer_save  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_layer_save);

    btn_cross.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_save.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_layer_save.setOnClickListener(this);

    layout_above = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.regsiter_layout_layer_above);

    createTableRows(name_list,id_list);



}

void createTableRows(ArrayList<String> list_name , ArrayList<String> list_id )
{
    /*-----R O W S   O F   T A B L E   C R E A T E D   D Y N A M I C A L L Y ------*/
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.register_save:

          layout_above.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
          btn_save.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);

        scroll.setEnabled(false);
        edit.setEnabled(false);
        edit.setClickable(false);
        scroll.setClickable(false);

        break;

    case R.id.register_cross:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cross Cancel", 1000).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestSave.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.register_layer_save:
        selectedInfo();
        break;

    } 

}`
```

Comment: So can you post youe code, which you tried?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take front layout's size as background layout's size and set front 
layout's background color transparent so background layout is partially
visible.
And  set onClickListener to front layout and in onClick method do nothing.

This answer is not exactly as you want but it is a good alternative.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Try using setFocusable(False); may be this should help you

Answer (score 0):

Try by working with children instead of the layout itself

```
LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.layout2);
                int num=l.getChildCount();
                for(int i=0;i<l.getChildAt(0);i++)
                    if(l.getChildAt(i).isClickable()||l.getChildAt(i).isEnabled()) 
                            {
l.getChildAt(i).setClickable(false);
l.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: this will not work if there are nested children for this layout. We need to set clickable false for every child & their sub-child as well.

I have posted a nested implementation for the same, below.

Answer (score 0):

You may use recursion for this and recursively disable clickable property for all the children-

```
public static void enableDisableViewGroup(ViewGroup viewGroup, boolean enabled) {
int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
  View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
  view.setEnabled(enabled);
  if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
    enableDisableViewGroup((ViewGroup) view, enabled);
  } else if (view instanceof ListView) {
    view.setEnabled(enabled);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view;
    int listChildCount = listView.getChildCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < listChildCount; j++) {
      listView.getChildAt(j).setEnabled(enabled);
    }
  }
}
}
```